# CommandBar AppBarButton Icon Size

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to redesign my `CommandBar AppBarButton` icons to look like Calendar, Mail, etc. Microsoft Apps.

As you can see below, Microsoft Apps icons are bigger smooth, thin than mine and also have vivid white color.

I've tried to apply resources, and other configurations like font size, height, width and nothing works, I have no idea how to do it.

This is my source code:

```
<Page.Resources>
    link to resouse file:
    https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/apps/mt299105.aspx
</Page.Resources>

<CommandBar Height="40" OverflowButtonVisibility="Collapsed" Background="Transparent" IsOpen="True" DefaultLabelPosition="Right">
    <CommandBar.Content>
        <TextBlock Text="X" FontFamily="SEGOE" Padding="10,0,0,0"/>
    </CommandBar.Content>
    <AppBarButton Icon="Save" Label="Save"/>
    <AppBarButton Icon="Delete" Label="Save"/>
    <AppBarButton Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle1}" Icon="Save" Label="Save"/>
    <AppBarButton Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle1}" Icon="Delete" Label="Delete"/>
</CommandBar>
```

[image]

Comment: You can restyle theirs if you'd like. You just crack open the style for it, copy it, and modify it how you want. Honestly though command bar doesn't have to be a complex control, I have a couple examples of the custom one I wrote called ContextRibbon. It's not too bad writing your own. https://github.com/DotNetRussell/UWPLibrary/tree/master/BasecodeLibrary/BasecodeLibrary/Controls

Comment: Yes I did adding this file (https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/apps/mt299105.aspx) to my page resource, but I can't find out how to design like MIcrosft Apss. @AnthonyRussell

Comment: @rubStackOverflow Have you resolved this question by my below reply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AppBarButton style which you mentioned in above comment is not the latest.

You could get the latest style by the following steps:

**Go to 'Document Outline -> Right Click your AppBarButton -> Edit Template -> Edit a Copy'**.

Then, you will find that `<ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>` is wrapped in a ViewBox. This ViewBox has a fixed height(16). You could change the height value that you want.

```
<Style x:Key="AppBarButtonStyle" TargetType="AppBarButton">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBackground}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForeground}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBorderBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="68" />
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}" />
        <Setter Property="AllowFocusOnInteraction" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="KeyboardAcceleratorPlacementMode" Value="Hidden" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="AppBarButton">
                    <Grid x:Name="Root" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}" MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding MaxWidth}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="FullSize" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Compact">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="LabelOnRight">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentViewbox" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonContentViewboxMargin}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="MinHeight">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeCompactHeight}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="TextAlignment">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Left" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource AppBarButtonTextLabelOnRightMargin}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="LabelCollapsed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="MinHeight">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeCompactHeight}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Overflow">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="ContentRoot.MinHeight" Value="0" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        <Setter Target="TextLabel.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="OverflowWithToggleButtons">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="ContentRoot.MinHeight" Value="0" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        <Setter Target="TextLabel.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Margin" Value="38,0,12,0" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="OverflowWithMenuIcons">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="ContentRoot.MinHeight" Value="0" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.Width" Value="16" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.Height" Value="16" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.Margin" Value="12,0,12,0" />
                                        <Setter Target="TextLabel.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Margin" Value="38,0,12,0" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="OverflowWithToggleButtonsAndMenuIcons">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="ContentRoot.MinHeight" Value="0" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.Width" Value="16" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.Height" Value="16" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.Margin" Value="38,0,12,0" />
                                        <Setter Target="TextLabel.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Margin" Value="76,0,12,0" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="Root.Background" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="Root.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="Content.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="TextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="KeyboardAcceleratorTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonKeyboardAcceleratorTextForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="Root.Background" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBackgroundPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="Root.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="Content.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="TextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="KeyboardAcceleratorTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonKeyboardAcceleratorTextForegroundPressed}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="Root.Background" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                        <Setter Target="Root.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                        <Setter Target="Content.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                        <Setter Target="TextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                        <Setter Target="KeyboardAcceleratorTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonKeyboardAcceleratorTextForegroundDisabled}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="OverflowNormal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="OverflowPointerOver">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="Root.Background" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="Root.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="Content.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="TextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="KeyboardAcceleratorTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonKeyboardAcceleratorTextForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="SubItemChevron.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonSubItemChevronForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="OverflowPressed">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="Root.Background" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBackgroundPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="Root.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="Content.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="TextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="KeyboardAcceleratorTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonKeyboardAcceleratorTextForegroundPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="SubItemChevron.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonSubItemChevronForegroundPressed}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="OverflowSubMenuOpened">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="Root.Background" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBackgroundSubMenuOpened}" />
                                        <Setter Target="Root.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBorderBrushSubMenuOpened}" />
                                        <Setter Target="Content.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundSubMenuOpened}" />
                                        <Setter Target="TextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundSubMenuOpened}" />
                                        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundSubMenuOpened}" />
                                        <Setter Target="KeyboardAcceleratorTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonKeyboardAcceleratorTextForegroundSubMenuOpened}" />
                                        <Setter Target="SubItemChevron.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonSubItemChevronForegroundSubMenuOpened}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="InputModeStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="InputModeDefault" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="TouchInputMode">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Padding" Value="{StaticResource AppBarButtonOverflowTextTouchMargin}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="GameControllerInputMode">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Padding" Value="{StaticResource AppBarButtonOverflowTextTouchMargin}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="KeyboardAcceleratorTextVisibility">
                                <VisualState x:Name="KeyboardAcceleratorTextCollapsed" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="KeyboardAcceleratorTextVisible">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="KeyboardAcceleratorTextLabel.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FlyoutStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="NoFlyout" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="HasFlyout">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="SubItemChevron.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid x:Name="ContentRoot" MinHeight="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeMinHeight}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Viewbox x:Name="ContentViewbox" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="50" Margin="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonContentViewboxCollapsedMargin}">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Height="20" />
                            </Viewbox>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="TextLabel" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="12" Margin="2,0,2,6" Grid.Row="1" Text="{TemplateBinding Label}" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" />
                            <TextBlock x:Name="OverflowTextLabel" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="12,0,12,0" Padding="{StaticResource AppBarButtonOverflowTextLabelPadding}" Text="{TemplateBinding Label}" TextTrimming="Clip" TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                            <TextBlock x:Name="KeyboardAcceleratorTextLabel" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonKeyboardAcceleratorTextForeground}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" MinWidth="{Binding TemplateSettings.KeyboardAcceleratorTextMinWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" Margin="24,0,12,0" Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" Text="{TemplateBinding KeyboardAcceleratorTextOverride}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                            <FontIcon x:Name="SubItemChevron" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Grid.Column="2" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Foreground="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutSubItemChevron}" FontSize="12" Glyph="&#xE0E3;" MirroredWhenRightToLeft="True" Margin="12,0,12,0" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

```
<CommandBar>
    <AppBarButton Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}" Label="add" Icon="Save">
    </AppBarButton>
</CommandBar>
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know why but `Edit a Copy` is disabled.

Comment: @rubStackOverflow Delete your previous style.

Comment: Ok, editing AppBarButton style make it completely disappear, some resources are tagged as like this `AppBarButton OverflowTextTouchMargin is not found`

Comment: @rubStackOverflow I've added the whole style in my above reply. Please directly copy it and apply it for your AppBarButton. Note: My project's target version is 17763

Comment: Ok, the size looks good but it's not smooth and thin like `Calendar App`, thanks anyway.