# how to change AppBarButton FontSize in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

The AppbarButton FontSize is Not Changed.

What I have tried is?

```
AppbarButton =new AppbarButton();
BitmapIcon BitmapIcon = new BitmapIcon();
BitmapIcon.UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Toolbar/Icons/image.png");
AppBarButton.IsCompact = false;
AppBarButton.Icon = BitmapIcon;
AppBarButton.FontSize = 10;
AppBarButton.Label = "Recommended PivotTable";
```

the label Size Won't changed?[image: my Appbarbutton look like this.label size won't changed]

Comment: After a bit of research I came across this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55470551/8293694
Give it a look.

Answer (score 2):

In the default `AppBarButton` style, Label's `FontSize` is fixed. 12px in non-overflow state and 15px in overflow state.

Copy the code below into `Page.Resources`.

```xml
<Style TargetType="AppBarButton" x:Key="BasicAppBarButtonStyle" x:Name="BasicAppBarButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonRevealBackground}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForeground}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonRevealBorderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonRevealBorderThemeThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="68" />
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}" />
    <Setter Property="AllowFocusOnInteraction" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="AppBarButton">
                <Grid x:Name="Root" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}" MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding MaxWidth}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" Margin="1,0">

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="FullSize" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Compact">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentViewbox" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonContentViewboxCompactMargin}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="LabelOnRight">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentViewbox" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonContentViewboxMargin}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="MinHeight">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeCompactHeight}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="TextAlignment">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Left" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonTextLabelOnRightMargin}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="LabelCollapsed">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="MinHeight">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeCompactHeight}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentViewbox" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonContentViewboxCompactMargin}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Overflow">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentRoot.MinHeight" Value="0" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                    <Setter Target="TextLabel.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="OverflowWithToggleButtons">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentRoot.MinHeight" Value="0" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                    <Setter Target="TextLabel.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Margin" Value="38,0,12,0" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="OverflowWithMenuIcons">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentRoot.MinHeight" Value="0" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.Width" Value="16" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.Height" Value="16" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.Margin" Value="12,0,12,0" />
                                    <Setter Target="TextLabel.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Margin" Value="38,0,12,0" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="OverflowWithToggleButtonsAndMenuIcons">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentRoot.MinHeight" Value="0" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.Width" Value="16" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.Height" Value="16" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentViewbox.Margin" Value="38,0,12,0" />
                                    <Setter Target="TextLabel.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Margin" Value="76,0,12,0" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver" />
                                    <Setter Target="Root.Background" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonRevealBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                    <Setter Target="Border.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonRevealBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                    <Setter Target="Content.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                    <Setter Target="TextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed" />
                                    <Setter Target="Root.Background" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonRevealBackgroundPressed}" />
                                    <Setter Target="Border.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonRevealBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                    <Setter Target="Content.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                    <Setter Target="TextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="Root.Background" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonRevealBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                    <Setter Target="Border.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonRevealBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                    <Setter Target="Content.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                    <Setter Target="TextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                    <Setter Target="KeyboardAcceleratorTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonKeyboardAcceleratorTextForegroundDisabled}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="OverflowNormal">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="OverflowPointerOver">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="Root.Background" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonRevealBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                    <Setter Target="Border.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonRevealBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                    <Setter Target="Content.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                    <Setter Target="TextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                    <Setter Target="KeyboardAcceleratorTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonKeyboardAcceleratorTextForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="OverflowPressed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="Root.Background" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonRevealBackgroundPressed}" />
                                    <Setter Target="Border.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonRevealBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                    <Setter Target="Content.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                    <Setter Target="TextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                    <Setter Target="KeyboardAcceleratorTextLabel.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonKeyboardAcceleratorTextForegroundPressed}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="InputModeStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="InputModeDefault" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="TouchInputMode">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Padding" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonOverflowTextTouchMargin}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="GameControllerInputMode">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Padding" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonOverflowTextTouchMargin}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="KeyboardAcceleratorTextVisibility">
                            <VisualState x:Name="KeyboardAcceleratorTextCollapsed" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="KeyboardAcceleratorTextVisible">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="KeyboardAcceleratorTextLabel.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>

                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid x:Name="ContentRoot" MinHeight="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeMinHeight}" Margin="-1,0">

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Viewbox x:Name="ContentViewbox"
                        Height="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonContentHeight}"
                        Margin="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonContentViewboxCollapsedMargin}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" >
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}"
                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                        </Viewbox>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TextLabel"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Text="{TemplateBinding Label}"
                        Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                        FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                        FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                        TextAlignment="Center"
                        TextWrapping="Wrap"
                        Margin="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonTextLabelMargin}"
                        AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="OverflowTextLabel"
                        Text="{TemplateBinding Label}"
                        Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                        FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                        FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                        TextAlignment="Left"
                        TextTrimming="Clip"
                        TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Margin="12,0,12,0"
                        Padding="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonOverflowTextLabelPadding}"
                        Visibility="Collapsed"
                        AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="KeyboardAcceleratorTextLabel"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"
                        Text="{TemplateBinding KeyboardAcceleratorTextOverride}"
                        MinWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.KeyboardAcceleratorTextMinWidth}"
                        Margin="24,0,12,0"
                        Foreground="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonKeyboardAcceleratorTextForeground}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Visibility="Collapsed"
                        AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                        <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="1,0" />

                    </Grid>

                </Grid>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Usage**

*xaml*

```xml
<AppBarButton Style="{StaticResource BasicAppBarButtonStyle}" FontSize="10"/>
```

*C#*

```cs
var appBarButton = new AppBarButton();
appBarButton.Style = BasicAppBarButtonStyle;
appBarButton.FontSize = 10;
```