# Prevent from setting properties in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, custom-attributes

I would like to implement some access restriction when creating a model. Presently my code looks moreless like this.

```
public Model GetModel()
{
    Model model = new Model();
    if (isAllowedToSet(Field.A))
        model.FieldA = 1;
    if (isAllowedToSet(Field.B))
        model.FieldB = 2;
    if (isAllowedToSet(Field.C))
        model.FieldC = 3;
    return model;
}
private bool isAllowedToSet(Field field)
{
    return (field == Field.A); //Here comes some real logic
}
class Model
{
    public int FieldA { get; set; }
    public int FieldB { get; set; }
    public int FieldC { get; set; }
}
```

How to do it smarter? I was thinking about using FieldAttribute, I have not found a solution though. Or is there another way?

Comment: if we get to basics.. does `private set;` work..?

Comment: I believe you should looking into the following articles from Microsoft's documentation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55470551/8293694
and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/restricting-accessor-accessibility as @irf suggested in his/hers comment.

Comment: Can you provide more information about the problem you are trying to solve? This seems pretty clunky. Your GetModel() looks like a factory method, could you provide different factories to different consumers that only populate a subset of properties?

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer sure - that is not the actual code, just wanted to keep things simple. GetModel is a service method, invoked in ApiController. It enriches the model with values that current user is allowed to see. These are checked in the database, so overriding the setter is not a great solution, because I would have to mix all the application layers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, you **could** do this with reflection and attributes

```
public class Model
{
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public int FieldA { get; set; }
    public int FieldB { get; set; }
    public int FieldC { get; set; }
}

public Model GetModel()
{
    Model model = new Model();

    if (isAllowedToSet(() => model.FieldA))
        model.FieldA = 1;

    if (isAllowedToSet(() => model.FieldB))
        model.FieldB = 2;

    if (isAllowedToSet(() => model.FieldC))
        model.FieldC = 3;

    return model;
}

private bool isAllowedToSet<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression)
{
    var propertyName = ((MemberExpression)propertyExpression.Body).Member.Name;            
    Attribute readonlyAtt = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)[propertyName].Attributes[typeof(ReadOnlyAttribute)];

    return readonlyAtt == null || readonlyAtt.Equals(ReadOnlyAttribute.No);
}
```

Whether you **should** or not is another matter entirely, since this seems like it's a fix for a problem that probably has a more elegant solution that does not involve reflection (which is slow apart from anything else).

If you can expand on why you are trying to do this, you may get a better response.